# How to get spring boot property file value as Map<String,String>

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In my project am having a requirement to retrieve a property file values in a map. This is how i wrote a code to retrieve property file value in a map. But values is not binding in the map. How can i achieve this.Is anything i missed?

**specialist.properties**

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "specialist")
@PropertySource("classpath:specialist.properties")
public class SpecialistProperties {


    private Map<String,String> specialist=new HashMap<String,String>();

public Map<String, String> getSpecialist() {
    return specialist;
}

public void setSpecialist(Map<String, String> specialist) {
    this.specialist = specialist;
}

}
```

Controller class:

```
@RestController
    public class MyappController {


        @Autowired
        private SpecialistProperties specialistProperties;

        @GetMapping(value="/specialist")
        public Map<String,String> getSpecialist()
        {
            return specialistProperties.getMap();
        }

    }
```

specialist.properties

```
specialist.name=Sam
specialist.availableDay=Wednesday
specialist.availableTime=5PM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake by adding the **@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="specialist")**. No need of **prefix="specialist"**. Because the map property value i have added as **specialist**, so there is no need of specialist in the ConfigurationProperties prefix. After the change it was worked good.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource("classpath:specialist.properties")
public class SpecialistProperties {


    private Map<String,String> prop=new HashMap<String,String>();

    public Map<String, String> getProp() {
        return prop;
    }

    public void setProp(Map<String, String> prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set properties as shown below.

Make a file with name: **application.properties** with following code:

```
    example.hello=Hello
    example.user=Abhimanyu
    example.howru=How are you?
    example.mapProperty.key1=MapValue1
    example.mapProperty.key2=MapValue2
    example.listProperty[0]=ListValue1
    example.listProperty[1]=ListValue2
```

OR:

Make a file with name: **application.yml** with the following code

```
    example:
      hello: Hello
    user: Abhimanyu
    howru: How are you?
    mapProperty:
      key1: MapValue1
      key2: MapValue2
    listProperty:
      ListValue1
      ListValue2
```

And you can verify/format your yaml file online by visiting https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-validator

For your reference refer following the link: http://jcombat.com/spring/how-to-read-properties-using-spring-boot-configurationproperties